# Assalaam vs Assalaamu alaikum

Tags: arabic

I have a grammar question. Would it be weird to say “assalaam” instead of “assalaamu alaikum” or “salaam”? I want to write it this way just for a piece of art (painting) for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Hi, actually using "Assalaam" as a shortened form of the Islamic greeting "Assalaamu Alaikum" can be acceptable for aesthetic reasons... but "Assalaamu Alaikum" is more formal.